webview2 NavigateToString goes to Microsoft.com
I know I am doing something dumb here, but I'm trying to pass in HTML as a string to the WebView2 control.
In the sub WebView_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebView.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted I am setting WebView.NavigateToString(HTML) The HTML variable holds my valid HTML content.
But once the control shows the page it is showing Microsoft.com which I assume is coming from the default Source setting on the control.
I've followed many example of doing this, looked at the specs, but I can't find anyone else reporting this behaviour.
